# Hook with jQuery in joomla squeeze box

Tags: jquery, joomla, mootools, joomla2.5

Situation is quite difficult and i don't have enough time to solve it properly, so is there any way to use jQuery with Joomla's squeeze box modal windows instead of MooTools. Not delete MooTools, but just use jQuery parallel. At the moment jQuery does not react on any id, class, and etc. Only helps `onclick="someFunctionName();"` in which is jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a lot more information or maybe a link in order to properly diagnose the issue.

However, chances are that you just need to call the noconflict function to eliminate the conflict.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

If that doesn't work, post some code so we can see what we are working with.

Comment: Please update your post and i will accept it. After adding noConflict also need to add `rel="handler: 'adopt'"` - by default it is `clone` (just founded it in joomla js source). After it all works fine.